# terraform azure Storage Account disable allow cross-tenant replication

Tags: azure, terraform

I need to configure in terraform a storage account with the option Allow cross-tenant replicant disable. How I can do it? What is the parameter? thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AllowCrossTenantReplication** is still in Preview so I don't think it will be in Terraform until it goes GA.  In the mean time, you can use Azure Policy to enforce this in your subscriptions.

#### Policy

([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/object-replication-prevent-cross-tenant-policies?tabs=azure-powershell#use-azure-policy-to-enforce-same-tenant-replication-policies))

```
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "field":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/allowCrossTenantReplication",
          "equals": "false"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the resource to apply this? is policy definition? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_definition

Comment: You can assign policy to a Management Group (think group of subscriptions), a subscription, or a Resource group.  Obviously the higher up you can apply, the stricter the control.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview#recommendations-for-managing-policies